# Is any precision difference between (float + int) and (float + (float)int) in C++?

Tags: c++

For example,

If I have `int A = 106` and `float B = 10.345f`, which operation has better precision, `A + B` or `(float)A + B`? Or do they actually have the same precision?

Comment: Why would there be a difference? - `A` will need to be converted in either case.

Comment: You'll have such problem with division, but not with addition nor the other operations. Also consider the type the result is casted to is important: `int C = A + B` will indeed incude lose of precision.

Comment: Use `double` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no difference. When adding two arithmetic types, there is a set of *implicit conversions* that are applied by the compiler. You can find a list of these rules for example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions). In your case rule number 3) applies:

> 3. Otherwise, if one operand is float, float complex, or float imaginary,
>    the other operand is implicitly converted as follows:
>
>    - integer type to float (the only real type possible is float, which
>      remains as-is)
>    - [...]

So if you do not explicitely state the conversion using a cast, the compiler implicitely does exactly the same conversion for you. And because the expressions are actually the same, there is also no difference in precision.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the compiler results https://godbolt.org/z/x5174j8n9, then you see that functions

```
float add1(int A, float B)
{
    return A + B;
}

float add2(int A, float B)
{
    return (float)A + B;
}
```

give identical compiler output with `O2` or `O3` optimization enabled:

```
add1(int, float):
        movaps  xmm1, xmm0
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
add2(int, float):
        movaps  xmm1, xmm0
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2ss        xmm0, edi
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```